# Data/profile export categories name instead of Ids (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9, php, csv, export, data

I have done this script to runs data/profile using ssh terminal to export csv data of all products inside of magento 1.9.
I need to have the category name (structure tree) instead of category Ids but i do not know how to do that.
Attached my code.

```
<?php
#$profileId = 1; #All Products
$profileId = 49; #OnSale
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$profile = Mage::getModel('dataflow/profile');
$userModel = Mage::getModel('admin/user');
$userModel->setUserId(0);
Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->setUser($userModel);
$profile->load($profileId);
if (!$profile->getId()) {
 Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError('[ERROR] Invalid ID');
}
Mage::register('current_convert_profile', $profile);
$profile->run();
$recordCount = 0;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem, check out my solution. To export category name instead of category Ids, you should unparse the file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Convert/Parser/Product.php by copy and replace this lines (around at 402 line)

https://gist.github.com/scgoeswild/272dce1dbb5d620ee8b922408fcc6a82#gistcomment-3528471